# How to create Dynamic Task Scheduling with AWS Lambdas?

Tags: dynamic, aws-lambda, cron-task

This is the requirement that I am trying to solve: I have a system of IoT things that uses AWS-Lambdas functions. The client wants to create a schedule for some devices to be turned on and off. For example, the client will setup the device1 to be turned on at 10:30AM and turned off at 14:00PM.

My first thought was to create a [Lambda Cron](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/reference-cron-and-rate-expressions.html) and make it to run every 1 min forever for each minute and check if is there an action in the database related to 1 or more devices. If yes, do the action.

This is clearly not a god pattern or inefficient.

I think the best scenario should be create the task dynamically but I don't know if it is possible with AWS - Lambdas.

The best option that I have found is to use [Dynamo with lambdas](https://medium.com/monstar-lab-bangladesh-engineering/how-i-solved-dynamic-task-scheduling-using-aws-dynamodb-ttl-stream-and-lambda-c0da5ebd6597). But the execution time is not accurated.

So, is there a way to accomplish this goal with AWS-lambdas? If yes how could I do that?

Answer (score -2):

You can create an AWS Cloud Watch rule and trigger your lambda according to your desired schedule
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html

Comment: I don't think this answers the question since the question clearly mentions that the task timing should be dynamic as per the client. Unfortunately that is not supported using CloudWatchEvent(EventBridge)